Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io"
I am setting up a k8s cluster in 2 ec2 instances.
I install cert-manager: kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.15.3/cert-manager.yaml
kubectl get node
NAME               STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
ip-172-31-31-197   Ready    <none>          39m   v1.31.1
ip-172-31-31-79    Ready    control-plane   41m   v1.31.1

kubectl get pod --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
cert-manager   cert-manager-7fbbc65b49-mj848              1/1     Running            0               30m
cert-manager   cert-manager-cainjector-6664fc84f6-v7w7q   1/1     Running            0               30m
cert-manager   cert-manager-webhook-59598898fd-cfvhp      1/1     Running            0               30m
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-5qtfz                      1/1     Running            0               37m
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-k8m7x                      1/1     Running            0               39m
kube-system    coredns-7c65d6cfc9-5qq2l                   1/1     Running            0               39m
kube-system    coredns-7c65d6cfc9-69t5n                   1/1     Running            0               39m
kube-system    etcd-ip-172-31-31-79                       1/1     Running            0               39m
kube-system    kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-31-79             1/1     Running            0               39m
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-31-79    1/1     Running            0               39m
kube-system    kube-proxy-4svnx                           1/1     Running            9 (6m39s ago)   37m
kube-system    kube-proxy-nbldj                           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   10 (98s ago)    39m
kube-system    kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-31-79             1/1     Running            0               39m


cmctl check api
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/validate?timeout=30s": context deadline exceeded
kubectl apply -f test-resources.yaml
namespace/cert-manager-test created
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "test-resources.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/validate?timeout=30s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "test-resources.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/validate?timeout=30s": context deadline exceeded

kubectl exec -it my-nginx -- curl -k https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443
404 page not found

look like "404 page not found" means we can reach cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443

I update inbound rules for ec2 to enable for all ports and it works. Figuring out which ports are needed for cert-manager...
